# LiveAgent: liveagent.prechat.findorcreate.map.doCreate Condition

Tags: visualforce, liveagent, chat, pre-chat, pre-chat-api

I have this code where I search if a contact or person account is found in the salesforce database based on the email that the customer input in the form. The issue is that even when I find the contact, the code is creating a person account.

When the customer inputs an email of a person account the issue does not happen.

I don't know if changing the order or creating a decision in the code would solve the issue, but as I'm new to coding I'm having trouble with this.

You can see below the code snippets of this part of finding, check if matches and then create the person account.

PS: I'm using the code sample provided by salesforce in this URL https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.live_agent_dev.meta/live_agent_dev/live_agent_pre_chat_forms_code_sample.htm

```python
<input type="hidden" name="liveagent.prechat.findorcreate.map.doFind:Contact" value="Email,true" />
<input type="hidden" name="liveagent.prechat.findorcreate.map.isExactMatch:Contact" value="Email,true" />
<input type="hidden" name="liveagent.prechat.findorcreate.map.doFind:Account" value="PersonEmail,true" />
<input type="hidden" name="liveagent.prechat.findorcreate.map.isExactMatch:Account" value="PersonEmail,true" />
<input type="hidden" name="liveagent.prechat.findorcreate.map.doCreate:Account" value="FirstName,true;LastName,true;PersonEmail,true;Phone,true;RecordTypeId,true" />
```